# mongoose $group (aggregation) returns duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a JobApplication collection which contains a jobseeker reference like so:

| _id | job_post | jobseeker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60b62fcf36c4bd19fc2a1733 | 60a59ca4b43549049baef311 | 60802ba5be283f6ffcf07821 |

and I want to find the number of jobseekers grouped by theirs countries

I tried to do it like this:

```
return await JobApplication.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: Jobseeker.collection.collectionName,
            localField: 'jobseeker',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'jobseeker'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$jobseeker'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$jobseeker.current_country_of_residence",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

but I'm getting a duplicated data like this:

```
"applicants_by_locations": [
{
    "_id": "606f4d2bbca7c6f2be0625f9",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": "606f4d2bbca7c6f2be0625f9",
    "count": 2
}]
```

I'm getting the same country _id twice instead of one _id with count: 3.

I'm not sure what's going on here!!

---

Updated Code:

```
await JobApplication.aggregate([     
{
         $lookup: {
             from: Jobseeker.collection.collectionName,
             localField: 'jobseeker',
             foreignField: '_id',
             as: 'jobseeker'
}     },
{         $unwind: '$jobseeker'     },
{         $group: {
             _id: "$jobseeker.current_country_of_residence",
             count: { $sum: 1 }         
}     },     
{
         $group: {
             _id: "$_id",
             count: { $sum: "$count" }
}     }
])
```

Comment: Group on country `_id` and sum the `count` field.

Comment: didn't work :( [@prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad). it gives the same result

Comment: You can post code you had tried and the returned results.

Comment: `await JobApplication.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: Jobseeker.collection.collectionName,
            localField: 'jobseeker',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'jobseeker'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$jobseeker'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$jobseeker.current_country_of_residence",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            count: { $sum: "$count" }
        }
    }
])`
[@prasad_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4679320/prasad)